# How I can filter my xml to a search value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

hi I want to translate my site for this I use a Xml file and with Linq to xml I want to get the value. here is my xml for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Languages>
  <values id="_hallo">
    <value value="DE" display="Hallo"></value>
    <value value="EN" display="Hello"></value>
    <value value="CS" display="Tschechisch"></value>
    <value value="ES" display="Spanisch"></value>
    <value value="ZH" display="德國的"></value>
  </values>
</Languages>
```

here is my c#:

```
private void SiteTranslate(string language)
        {
            string BrowserLanguage = Request.UserLanguages[0].ToString().Substring(0, 2).ToUpper(); // here I get "DE" or "EN" etc..

            string btnadd_id = "_hallo"; // for example

            XDocument x = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\SiteLanguage.xml"));


            string val = from tep in x.Descendants("values").Where(el => el.Attribute("id").Value == btnadd_id).
                             Descendants("value").
                             Where(l => l.Attribute("value").Value == language).Select //?????? :( 

            BtnAdd.Text = val;
        }
```

Comment: Why not use Resource file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple "get the one and only element" problem:

```
 string val = x.Descendants("values")
       .Where(el => el.Attribute("id").Value == btnadd_id)
       .Elements("value")
       .Where(l => l.Attribute("value").Value == language)
       .SingleOrDefault()
       .Attribute("display").Value;
```

Comment: I think I fixed it now, still untested though.